# Most Efficient way to do a swipe animation in Xamarin.forms - Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, swipe, xamarin.forms

I had to implement a way to navigate between different element that are stacked in xamarin.forms. In the code below, you can see that we already manage the ability to distinguish every single one of the child of the container. At the moment, what I have written works but I need some help figuring out if it’s the good way or if there is a better way or even, if I can improve what I’ve done.

Currently, when you swipe from left to right or whatever move, I just use a SimpleOnGestureListener.
Here are some samples of what we are currently achieving:

[image]

[image]

I declared my custom elements such as the container & the children and then I created the customRenderer for each of them in an android library (only working on android at the moment).

“MyContent” is simply a modified frame with a specific Draw method and an event for each move available (up, down, left, right).

**Code of the container**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Elements
{
    public class MyContainer : Layout<MyContent>
    {
        public MyContainer ()
        {
        }

        protected override void LayoutChildren (double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count ; i++) {
                MyContent child =  Children[i];
                // skip invisible children
                if(!child.IsVisible)
                    continue;
                int soffset = Children.Count - i;
                int eoffset = soffset - 1;
                Rectangle startBoundingRegion = new Rectangle (12 * soffset + Padding.Left, 14 * soffset + Padding.Top, width - 24 * soffset, height - 8 * soffset);
                Rectangle endBoundingRegion = new Rectangle (12 * eoffset + Padding.Left, 14 * eoffset + Padding.Top, width - 24 * eoffset, height - 8 * eoffset);
                child.OriginalBounds = endBoundingRegion;
                LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion (child,startBoundingRegion);
                child.LayoutTo(endBoundingRegion,100,Easing.Linear);
            }
        }

        protected override SizeRequest OnSizeRequest (double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            var height = 0;
            var minHeight = 0;
            var width = 0;
            var minWidth = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < Children.Count; i++) {
                MyContent child =  Children[i];
                // skip invisible children

                if(!child.IsVisible)
                    continue;
                var childSizeRequest = child.GetSizeRequest (double.PositiveInfinity, height);
                height = (int)Math.Max (height, childSizeRequest.Minimum.Height);
                minHeight = (int)Math.Max (minHeight, childSizeRequest.Minimum.Height);
                width += (int)childSizeRequest.Request.Width;
                minWidth += (int)childSizeRequest.Minimum.Width;
            }

            return new SizeRequest (new Size (width, height), new Size (minWidth, minHeight));
        }
    }
}
```

**Code of its renderer**

```
{using ...}

[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(MyContainer), typeof(MyContainerRenderer))]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MyContainerRenderer : ViewRenderer<Layout<MyContent>,Android.Views.View>
    {
        private readonly MyContentGestureListener listener;
        private readonly GestureDetector detector;

        private bool isAnimating;
        private MyContent currentMyContent;

        public MyContainerRenderer ()
        {
            listener = new MyContentGestureListener();
            detector = new GestureDetector(listener);
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Layout<MyContent>> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement == null)
            {
                this.Touch -= HandleTouch;
                listener.OnSwipeLeft -= HandleOnSwipeLeft;
                listener.OnSwipeRight -= HandleOnSwipeRight;
                listener.OnSwipeTop -= HandleOnSwipeTop;
                listener.OnSwipeDown -= HandleOnSwipeDown;
                listener.OnPanVertical -= HandleOnPanVertical;
                listener.OnPanHorizontal -= HandleOnPanHorizontal;
            }

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                this.Touch += HandleTouch;
                listener.OnSwipeLeft += HandleOnSwipeLeft;
                listener.OnSwipeRight += HandleOnSwipeRight;
                listener.OnSwipeTop += HandleOnSwipeTop;
                listener.OnSwipeDown += HandleOnSwipeDown;
                listener.OnPanVertical += HandleOnPanVertical;
                listener.OnPanHorizontal += HandleOnPanHorizontal;
            }
        }

        void HandleTouch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
        {
            currentMyContent = ((MyContainer)this.Element).Children.Last();
            if (!isAnimating) {
                if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down) {
                    currentMyContent.ScaleTo (1.01, 100, Easing.Linear);
                } else if ( e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up){
                    if (!isAnimating) {
                        isAnimating = true;
                        currentMyContent.ScaleTo (1, 100, Easing.Linear);
                        currentMyContent.LayoutTo (currentMyContent.OriginalBounds, 100, Easing.CubicIn);
                        isAnimating = false;
                        listener.ResetFlags ();
                    }
                }

                detector.OnTouchEvent (e.Event);
            }
        }

        void HandleOnPanVertical(object sender, EventArgs distanceY)
        {
            Rectangle dest = new Rectangle (currentMyContent.Bounds.X,currentMyContent.Bounds.Y -  ((EventArgs<float>)distanceY).Value,currentMyContent.Bounds.Width,currentMyContent.Bounds.Height);
            currentMyContent.Layout(dest);
        }

        void HandleOnPanHorizontal(object sender, EventArgs distanceX)
        {
            Rectangle dest = new Rectangle (currentMyContent.Bounds.X - ((EventArgs<float>)distanceX).Value,currentMyContent.Bounds.Y,currentMyContent.Bounds.Width,currentMyContent.Bounds.Height);
            currentMyContent.Layout (dest);
        }

        async void animateNext (MyContent mContent, Rectangle dest)
        {
            isAnimating = true;

            await mContent.LayoutTo (dest, 150, Easing.Linear);
            ((MyContainer)this.Element).Children.Remove (mContent);
            ((MyContainer)this.Element).Children.Insert (0, mContent);
            isAnimating = false;
        }

        void HandleOnSwipeLeft(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentMyContent.OnSwipeLeft();
            Rectangle dest = new Rectangle (currentMyContent.Bounds.X,currentMyContent.Bounds.Y,currentMyContent.Bounds.Width,currentMyContent.Bounds.Height);
            dest.Left -= Width;
            animateNext (currentMyContent, dest);
        }

        void HandleOnSwipeRight(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentMyContent.OnSwipeRight();
            Rectangle dest = new Rectangle (currentMyContent.Bounds.X,currentMyContent.Bounds.Y,currentMyContent.Bounds.Width,currentMyContent.Bounds.Height);
            dest.Left += Width;
            animateNext (currentMyContent, dest);
        }

        void HandleOnSwipeTop(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                Rectangle dest = new Rectangle (currentMyContent.Bounds.X, currentMyContent.Bounds.Y, currentMyContent.Bounds.Width, currentMyContent.Bounds.Height);
                dest.Top -= Height;
                animateNext (currentMyContent, dest);
        }

        void HandleOnSwipeDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Rectangle dest = new Rectangle (currentMyContent.Bounds.X,currentMyContent.Bounds.Y,currentMyContent.Bounds.Width,currentMyContent.Bounds.Height);
            dest.Top += Height;
            animateNext (currentMyContent, dest);
        }
    }

    class MyContentGestureListener : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
    {
        private static int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 50;
        private static int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 20;

        private bool isPanningV;
        private bool isPanningH;

        public event EventHandler OnSwipeDown;
        public event EventHandler OnSwipeTop;
        public event EventHandler OnSwipeLeft;
        public event EventHandler OnSwipeRight;

        public event EventHandler OnPanHorizontal;
        public event EventHandler OnPanVertical;

        public override bool OnScroll(MotionEvent ev1, MotionEvent ev2,float distanceX,float distanceY)
        {
            if (Math.Abs (distanceX) > Math.Abs (distanceY) && OnPanHorizontal != null && !isPanningV) {
                isPanningH = true;
                OnPanHorizontal (this,new EventArgs<float> (distanceX));
            } else if (OnPanVertical != null && !isPanningH) {
                isPanningV = true;
                OnPanVertical (this, new EventArgs<float> (distanceY));
            }

            return base.OnScroll (ev1, ev2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }

        public override bool OnFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
        {
            float diffY = e2.GetY() - e1.GetY();
            float diffX = e2.GetX() - e1.GetX();

            if (Math.Abs(diffX) > Math.Abs(diffY) && Math.Abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.Abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
            {
                if (diffX > 0 && OnSwipeRight != null)
                {
                    OnSwipeRight (this, null);
                    isPanningH = false;
                }
                else if (OnSwipeLeft != null) {
                    OnSwipeLeft (this, null);
                    isPanningH = false;
                }
            }
            else if (Math.Abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.Abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
            {
                if (diffY > 0 && OnSwipeDown != null)
                {
                    OnSwipeDown (this, null);
                    isPanningV = false;
                }
                else if (OnSwipeTop != null) {
                    OnSwipeTop (this, null);
                    isPanningV = false;
                }
            }
            return base.OnFling (e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }

        public void ResetFlags(){
            isPanningH = false;
            isPanningV = false;
        }
    }

    public class EventArgs<T> : EventArgs
    {
        public EventArgs(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public T Value { get; private set; }
    }
}
```